# Access to log folder with Vagrant

Tags: apache, logging, vagrant

I've got a vagrant file which mounts a box with apache.

I would like to access the log directory (/var/log/apache2) of the guest directly in my host using sync folder mechanism (and not vagrant ssh !)

I've tried :

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./log/", "/var/log/apache2/"
```

The problem is that my log directory is empty and overrides the /var/log/apache2 making it empty (when I look at it by vagrant ssh). So the error.log file (stored in /var/log/apache2/error.log) is not synchronized to my guest folder ./log (which remains empty) and moreover is erased during the setup of the guest.

How can I configure vagrant to make the synchronization from guest to host and not the other side (host to guest) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your host OS, the following vagrant plugin could help you:

https://github.com/Learnosity/vagrant-nfs_guest

Basically the plugin relies on NFS for exporting folders on the guest and mounting it on the host.